# Sending message to devices through SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, shoryuken

I'm still learning about SQS, I did some successful tests with SQS and a Ruby application with Shoryuken that picks up the messages.  This works fine. We want to get 1000 IoT devices installed in people's homes.  These devices will send events to the backend, which will be picked up.  So far so good.

Now we also need to send messages back to the devices (less frequent, but still). Will I be able to use SQS for this too?  How can I target the device?

Do I need to add a MessageAttribute to identity the destination?  Or create a queue per device?

What are the best practises here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQS is definitely **not** the right tool to use for sending messages to individual devices, and while a queue per device may work, I would not recommend it (1000+ devices regularly polling for messages can get expensive).

Take a look at [Amazon IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-iot.html), in particular the [message broker component](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-message-broker.html).